# Java string.split("\\n")

Tags: java, split

```
String[] lines = ascii.getText().split("\\n");
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    System.out.println(lines[i]);
    if(lines[i] == "")
        System.out.println("abc");
}
```

`ascii` is a JTextArea. This is a sample code I'm just testing it before I put it in my program. Right now it splits the lines from ascii into separate strings, and then displays them.

It does that correctly and includes the empty lines which I want. Now I want to check if line is empty (it can contain only spaces). I've tried with combinations of

```
if(lines[i] == "", " ", "\n"...)
```

but none of those worked. Can anyone explain how to do it?

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail (I am not sure what you mean by "*but what is actually in the empty string?*")? Anyway [don't compare strings with `==`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: `String#trim#isEmpty` is a pretty good start

Comment: Yeah, if there's an empty line, I want to mark that in the output file. So I need to know that empty line is saved at in the lines array

Comment: I tried lines[i].compareTo("", " ", and "\n") and they all returned can't convert from int to boolean

Comment: Because `compareTo` returns an integer for sorting purposes

Comment: The crux of the problem above is that you are doing a reference equality check for `""`, not comparing the string values.  You need to use `.equals`.  However, the suggested `.isEmpty()` approach seems easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but what is actually in the empty string? I've tried if(lines[i] == "", " ", "\n"... and none of those worked. Can anyone help explain or lead me to what thats called?

If the empty line contains only white space characters, you can remove them using [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) and call [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

```
if (lines[i].trim().isEmpty()) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, will mark as answer in 2 mins